# Get first 200 chats with td api

Tags: java, android, api, telegram

I am using TdApi to get first 200 chats but i can not get, I just get first 100 chats. here are my codes that i tried to get 200 chats but unsuccessful.

Even I read the documentation at [here](https://javadoc.tlgrm.ru/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi.GetChats.html)

> Returns list of chats in the right order, chats are sorted by (order, chatId) in decreasing order. For example, to get list of chats from the beginning, the offsetOrder should be equal 2^63 - 1.

```
TdApi.GetChats getChats = new TdApi.GetChats(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0, 200);
TG.getClientInstance().send(getChats, new Client.ResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(TdApi.TLObject object) {
    TdApi.Chats chat = (TdApi.Chats) object;
    final TdApi.Chat[] chats2 = chat.chats;
    Log.e("test", "2 " + chats2.length + "");
    Log.e("test", "2 " + chats2[0].title + "");
});
```

Even I tried this:

```
TdApi.GetChats getchats1 = new TdApi.GetChats(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0, 100);
TG.getClientInstance().send(getchats1, new Client.ResultHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(TdApi.TLObject object) {
     TdApi.Chats chat = (TdApi.Chats) object;
     final TdApi.Chat[] chats2 = chat.chats;
     Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats2.length + "");
     Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats2[0].title + "");

     TdApi.GetChats getChats2 = new TdApi.GetChats(0, chats2[99].id, 100);
     TG.getClientInstance().send(getChats2, new Client.ResultHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(TdApi.TLObject object) {
         TdApi.Chats chat = (TdApi.Chats) object;
         final TdApi.Chat[] chats3 = chat.chats;
         Log.e("OkHttp hey", "3 " + chats3.length + "");
         Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats3[0].title + "");
    });
});
```

Or this :

```
TdApi.GetChats getchats1 = new TdApi.GetChats(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0, 100);
TG.getClientInstance().send(getchats1, new Client.ResultHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(TdApi.TLObject object) {
     TdApi.Chats chat = (TdApi.Chats) object;
     final TdApi.Chat[] chats2 = chat.chats;
     Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats2.length + "");
     Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats2[0].title + "");

     TdApi.GetChats getChats2 = new TdApi.GetChats(Long.MAX_VALUE-100, 0, 100);
     TG.getClientInstance().send(getChats2, new Client.ResultHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(TdApi.TLObject object) {
         TdApi.Chats chat = (TdApi.Chats) object;
         final TdApi.Chat[] chats3 = chat.chats;
         Log.e("OkHttp hey", "3 " + chats3.length + "");
         Log.e("OkHttp hey", "2 " + chats3[0].title + "");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this exaple: https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/cpp/td_example.cpp

For get all chats I use this code:

**Variables**

```
//...
int64_t offset_order_ = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
int64_t offset_chat_id_ = 0;
//...
```

**In update_chats function**

```
//for get next 100
if (chats->chat_ids_.size() > 0) {
    auto last_chat_id = chats->chat_ids_[chats->chat_ids_.size() - 1];
    send_query(td_api::make_object<td_api::getChat>(last_chat_id), [this](Object o){
        if (o->get_id() == td_api::error::ID) {
            return;
        }

        auto chat = td::move_tl_object_as<td_api::chat>(o);
        offset_order_ = chat->order_;
        offset_chat_id_ = chat->id_;
        update_chats_ = true;

        // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    });
}
```

**In loop function**

```
if (update_chats_) {
    send_query(td_api::make_object<td_api::getChats>(offset_order_, offset_chat_id_, 100), 
            std::bind(&TgClient::update_chats, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    update_chats_ = false;
}
```